# Read env variable from spring application.yml file for app deployement on cloud foundry

Tags: java, spring, keycloak, cloud-foundry

I have keycloak deployed as application on cloud foundry, and I have another application as spring boot application that has the `URI` of the keycloak on application.yml file.

How can I set the value of this `URI` that define on the keycloak application environment variable (VCAP_APPLICTION)? all the examples that I found was about

*How to access the "service" environment variable from properties file not the "application" environment variables*.

the application.yml file is like this:

```
rpt-verification-url: ${cloud.app.keycloak.uris[0]}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851758/keycloak-standalone-cluster-on-cloud-foundry/55934856

Answer (score 1):

You mention uri of another service, passed in through a properties file. This is an anti-pattern for cloud native development.

The uri of the keycloak application your app depends on, is not in your control. The keycloak app can crash and a new instance could be spun up in pcf. Or, some one can scale the app instance.

The approach in cloud native world is to use Spring Cloud Services Service Discovery (aka Netflix Eureka) pattern. Here is a link to [service discovery](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery).

And to pass runtime properties use the Config Server from Spring Cloud Services.

This is assuming, your keycloak app is deployed and running on PCF.

If it is external to PCF, you should look at User Provided Services (CUPS) or Service Broker on PCF.

Comment: You should watch [this session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lCEzgkdfds) on SCS from S1P.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `cf set-env` to set any environment variable for your application. If your app is called `myapp` the command below should allow you to set environment variable.

`set env myapp RPT_VERIFICATION_URL https://urltokeycloack`

SpringBoot has support for externalized configurations as documented in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) So if you set an OS environment variable for the process with the same name as the property name in the YAML file or .properties file SpringBoot will read that. `cf set-env` allows you set an environment variable for an application running on Cloud Foundry.

You can also set the environment vars in your `manifest.yml` file that you are using with your cf push.

Another choice is to use spring cloud config server and externalize all your app configuration files into a git repo. This is the best long term solution as suggested in the answer from K.AJ however if you are wanting to get something up and running quickly you can just use `cf set-env`