# Keycloak standalone cluster on Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, keycloak

How to configure Keycloak standalone cluster on Cloud Foundry?

I tried to use docker image `jboss/keycloak:4.5.0.Final` with internal routing:

- env:

  - `JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL: dns.DNS_PING`
  - `JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES: dns_query=keycloak-cluster-poc.apps.internal`
- all udp and tcp ports between app instances opened:

  ```sh
  cf add-network-policy keycloak-cluster-poc --destination-app keycloak-cluster-poc --protocol tcp/udp --port 1-65535
  ```

It's not working. Should I expose additional ports?

```xml
<socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" interface="private" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" interface="private" port="7600"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" interface="private" port="57600"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="private" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" interface="private" port="54200"/>
<socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
```

Comment: Is it trying to use multicast? That might be a problem. Can you configure it without using multicast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own question.

Go to this [keycloak4cf](https://github.com/i6e/keycloak4cf/blob/master/README-more.md#quick-start) repo if you are looking for a quick solution.

---

Main problems that I had to face:

#### Keycloak minimal version

Use the `jboss/keycloak:5.0.0` or newer/latest

There is [hardcoded](https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/commit/91f6c03d2fb48e2c896f8a5d05ac8e6a895a77dc#diff-820c741e3ab91b3967cd392b7ddcc1efL25) `.svc.cluster.local` DNS query suffix removed with [JGRP-2295](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JGRP-2295).

This fix was released in `JGroups 4.0.15.Final`, that is used in `Infinispan Core 9.4.0.Final.`, released with `Keycloak 5.0.0` (included `inifnispan-core 9.4.3.Final`).

#### Clustering

Clustering have to be done with TCP instead of [multicast UDP](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/WildFly_Clustering_without_Multicast) (there is no multicast on Cloud Foundry - thank you @DanielMikusa for the tip).

To change this config use `dns.DNS_PING.cli`:

```sh
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
batch
/subsystem=jgroups:write-attribute(name=default-stack,value=tcp)
/subsystem=jgroups/channel=ee:write-attribute(name=stack,value=tcp)
/subsystem=jgroups/stack=udp/protocol=PING:remove()
/subsystem=jgroups/stack=udp/protocol=$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol:add(add-index=0, properties=$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol_properties)
/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=MPING:remove()
/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol:add(add-index=0, properties=$keycloak_jgroups_discovery_protocol_properties)
run-batch
stop-embedded-server
```

Add network policy to allow connections between cluster nodes:

```
cf add-network-policy keycloak-cluster-poc --destination-app keycloak-cluster-poc --protocol tcp --port 7600
```

Comment: Do you know how is it resolved in keycloak the bind address? I use in my stack Infinispan+JGroups and hardcoding addres to `127.0.0.1` does not allow connections from outside (obviously ^^').

Comment: @lucasvc internal routing / BOSH DNS -  https://github.com/i6e/keycloak4cf/blob/master/README-more.md#quick-start

Comment: I got it working after in JGroups config set `TCP bind_addr=` the value from BOSH environment variable `CF_INSTANCE_INTERNAL_IP`.